# Failed to start couchbase-server.service: Unit couchbase-server.service failed to load

Tags: fedora, couchbase

When I run this command to install Couchbase Server

```
sudo rpm --install couchbase-server-community-4.0.0.centos7.x86_64.rpm
```

in my Fedora 22, I got an error below:

> Starting couchbase-server (via systemctl): Failed to start couchbase-server.service: Unit couchbase-server.service failed to load: No such file or directory. [Failed]
>
> You have successfully installed Couchbase Server.

How can I fixed this error?

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ . You'll probably get better answers on UnixSE than SO.

Comment: @Narendra Thanks for your reply. I will try. :)